# Error "sketch_apr12a:1:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>" Arduino code

Tags: arduino

Estoy haciendo un carro a control remoto y me sale este mensaje al compilar el código

Carro_a_control_remoto:1:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or 
#include &amp;amp;lt;IRremote.h&amp;gt;
^
Carro_a_control_remoto:2:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or 
#include &amp;amp;lt;IRremoteInt.h&amp;amp;gt;
^
exit status 1
#include expects "FILENAME" or

Código:

```
    #include &amp;amp;amp;lt;IRremote.h&amp;amp;gt;
#include &amp;amp;amp;lt;IRremoteInt.h&amp;amp;amp;gt;
int input_pin = 2;
IRrecv irrecv(imput_pin);
decode_results signals;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
}
void loop()
if (irrecv.decode(&amp;amp;amp;amp;signals)) {
  Serial.println(signals.value,HEX);
  irrecv.resume();
}
}
```

Comment: ¿No será `#include <IRremote.h>` e `#include <IRremoteInt.h>`?

Comment: @CandidMoe  si lo cambio me sale esto;      'amp' was not declared in this scope
 if (irrecv.decode(&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;signals)) {
Carro_a_control_remoto:12:23: error: expected ')' before ';' token
 if (irrecv.decode(&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;signals)) {
Carro_a_control_remoto:12:24: error: 'amp' was not declared in this scope
 if (irrecv.decode(&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;signals)) {
                        ^~~
Carro_a_control_remoto:12:47: error: expected ';' before ')' token
 if (irrecv.decode(&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;signals)) {
exit status 1
'amp' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Parece que estás copiando el código HTML de alguna parte. Prueba escribiendolo a mano.

Comment: @CandidMoe     Ya lo escribí a mano, me sale lo mismo de FILENAME

Comment: Mejor edita tu pregunta con la última versión del código y el último error. Si no, nadie entendera nada.

Comment: jeje ok gracias